# Facing barriers when running skl script from excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, jython, sikuli-script, vba

I am using below VB to launch script of **sikuliX 1.1.2** from excel but it takes around *30 seconds* to just execute the script and then script takes itself another seconds to fulfill the instruction. So is there any way to make this process very fast ?

VB Code:

```
Private Sub()

Dim dblRetVal As String

dblRetVal = Shell("java -jar E:\SikuliX1.1.2\sikulix.jar -r 
 D:\ProjectKiosk\Scripts\test2.sikuli —a1 a2 a3", vbHide)

End Sub()
```

Sikuli Script:

```
try:
click("1514219960059.png")
except:
# Your action where there is some problem.
doubleClick("1514219980851.png")
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some VBA specific improvements that can be made which I am not aware of but generally speaking, yes. Sikuli takes quite a while to load the JVM and even start running the script which by itself will take some time. Having said that, 30 seconds does sound like a bit too long. I wouldn't expect anything longer than ~10 seconds. Can you monitor the resources and see what is consuming them when Sikuli loads? Is this the java process or the VBA?

Comment: it is Java process because when I call sikuli script directly from command prompt, it is also take around 30 seconds to execute.

Comment: So it is not related to VBA as I thought. Sikuli is know to take a while to load and I am not aware of any ways how this can be improved.